# VueJS2: Drop down menus and navigating away: If user returns to menu, how to pre-select the option he had chosen?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a form with a dropdown list of country options like so:

[image]

When the user selects an option, the form will load some data from an API so the user can make changes. However, some parts of the form have some deeply nested components where the user can edit additional data on a separate page. The problem is that when the user changes navigation and then clicks the back button on the browser, the drop down list is 'reset' and he has to select again the country that he was editing.

Can someone suggest a way to handle this issue so that if user clicks the back button on his browser (or the page has a "back to results link"), he will go back to the form and it will already be pre-selected with his option?

Should I be handling this via $route.query, localstorage, vuex? I would prefer not to use Vuex but I guess I can if needed.

Is $router query all i need here? I can capture the country's id and run the API call again on navigation back to the drop down selection page?

Example data from API:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Afghanistan'
}
```

When user selects a country from menu, I run an API get request like so:

```
async setSelectedCountryObj(value) {
      if (value) {
        const response = await APIService.tempISOCountryById(value.code)
        ....snip...
```

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to handle with router, but that not a good way, you should go with vuex, that best way, just create store, and dispatch after select value, and always get value when come on that component, that essay not that much difficult, let me know if you need but i know you can.